# Объязаности контроллера в php

Tags: php, mvc

Никто не видел табличку разделения объязаностей между моделлю и контроллером?
Проясните какие функции относятся к контроллеру в пхп.
Прочитал пару статей я понял что он занимается обработкой параметров GET, POST и в зависимости от их значения вызываются отдельные методы.
Хочется правильно разделять код между контроллером и моделлю.Спасибо.
Какая часть работы с БД относится к нему? Где идет валидация данных?Обработка форм?

Comment: скажите, а почему вы не пользуетесь гуглом?

Comment: Может вас это удивит ,но я там искал.

Comment: зависит от идеологии фреймворка, если пишете фреймворк сами, то от вашей идеологии.

Comment: >Может вас это удивит ,но я там искал.

да, меня это удивляет, потому что гугл полон до верхов всяческой информацией о реализации MVC, в том числе и конкретно в php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так: есть файл index.php в нём, мы мы смотрим текущий урл и разбиваем его на составные части с помощью explode, к примеру урл был такого вида - http://site.ru/user/register/ - тут всё просто, урл можно разбить на user и register, где юзер название модели, потом просто, когда есть название модели, мы можем проверить существование её, и вызвать её, также, если есть ещё что, в данном случае register, в случае ООП - это метод (функция) и мы будем вызывать её, если нет никакого метода, то есть так: http://site.ru/user/ то, в модели у нас должен быть метод index() который будет вызываться если нет других роутеров, также в хтаккесс, нам нужно будем сделать переадресацию всех запросов на файл index.php

Это в паттерн проектирования MVC вроде так) примеров MVC море, гугл в помощь

Answer (score 0):

Контроллер (англ. controller — регулятор, управляющее устройство),
Моде́ль (фр. modèle, от лат. modulus — «мера, аналог, образец») — это упрощенное представление реального устройства и/или протекающих в нем процессов, явлений.

т.е. получается всю логику и поведение описываем в моделях а в контроллере управляем этими моделями